# How to disable right click on certain html page with some exceptions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now I'm using this code to disable right click :

```
$("body")
      .attr('ondragstart', 'return false')
      .attr('onselectstart', 'return false');

    var message='Right click is disabled on this page!';
    function clickIE4() {
      if (event.button==2) {
        alert(message);
        return false;
      }
    }

    function clickNS4(e) {
      if (document.layers||document.getElementById&&!document.all) {
        if (e.which==2||e.which==3) {
          alert(message);
          return false;
        }
      }
    }

    if (document.layers) {
      document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
      document.onmousedown=clickNS4;
    } else if (document.all&&!document.getElementById) {
      document.onmousedown=clickIE4;
    }
    document.oncontextmenu = new Function('alert(message); return false');
```

Now I have implemented context menu of my own and I'm displaying it when clicked on certain `a` element with class `.context`.

I'm using http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html

So I'd like to disable all right click context menus except the one with `.context` class

Comment: You must have copy-pasted this from somewhere that hasn't been updated in something like 10 years

Comment: There is really no foolproof way to disable right-clicks. Anyone can view your source and take whatever they want. Or even open it up in Firebug or another program and disable the scripts in real time. It won't accomplish much except to irritate your users.

Comment: I agree, it´s a very bad practice from an usability point of view. You gain absolutely nothing except from an maybe annoyed user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
 $('body *:not(.context)').on('contextmenu', function (evt) {
     evt.preventDefault();
 });
```

EDIT: This seems to work better:

```
 $(document).on('contextmenu', function (evt) {
     if (!$(evt.target).is('.context')) {
         evt.preventDefault();
     }   
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet:

```
var message="Right click is disabled on this page!";
jQuery("*").on("contextmenu", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($(this).hasClass("context")) {
        alert("Opening custom right-click menu.");
    }
    else {
        alert(message);
    }
    return false;
});
```

**[See a demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/tjSXR/1/)**